# how can I play video (streaming) in RoR...??? when i have video uploaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video-streaming, carrierwave

im the beginner developer of ruby on rails.
im trying to make system.

User can save the video file and if user upload the video file, it can be shown.

my model condition.
I have Article model(table) and my article have params include video column.
i want user can upload video(limited file size..), and show the video to others on the articles.html.erb.

now,
I can upload video and see the articles_path view page. But, I can't load and play the video.

And, in my console  the video saved by

"#ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00......."

```
#<VideoUploader:0x00007fcb5c600bb0 @model=#<Article id: 1, title: "2care", desc: "qhthqhth", picture: nil, user_id: 1, created
_at: "2021-02-19 16:12:46", updated_at: "2021-02-19 16:12:46", hit: nil, category: nil, video: "#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0
x00007fb671d...">, @mounted_as=:video, @staged=false, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x0000564ffa60d7b8 @file=".../public/system/carrierwave/article/video/1/#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fb671d2eab8>", @original_filename=nil, @co
ntent_type=nil, @content=nil>, @filename=nil, @cache_id=nil, @identifier="#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fb671d2eab8>"  @
```

versions={:rescaled=>#<VideoUploader::Uploader70255711602180:0x0000564ffa60cfc0 @model=#<Article id: 1, title: "2care", desc: "qh
thqhth", picture: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2021-02-19 16:12:46", updated_at: "2021-02-19 16:12:46", hit: nil, category: nil, vide
o: "#ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fb671d...", @mounted_as=:video, @staged=false, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x0
0007fcb5c60f4d0 @file=".../public/system/carrierwave/article/video/1/rescaled_#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFil
e:0x00007fb671d2eab8>", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil, @content=nil>, @filename=nil, @cache_id=nil, @identifier="#", @versions={}, @parent_version=#<VideoUploader:0x00007fcb5c600bb0 ...>, @storage=#<Ca
rrierWave::Storage::File:0x0000564ffa60c048 @uploader=#<VideoUploader::Uploader70255711602180:0x0000564ffa60cfc0 ...> .....

like that.

https://admatbandara.medium.com/video-upload-processing-with-ruby-on-rails-c3c5aa04e08
This is what I referenced.

in my gemfile

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-video'
gem 'streamio-ffmpeg'
gem 'carrierwave-video-thumbnailer' 
gem 'carrierwave_backgrounder', git: 'https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder' 
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

in my video_uploader.rb

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  require 'streamio-ffmpeg'
  include CarrierWave::Video
  include CarrierWave::Video::Thumbnailer
# For carrierwave_backgrounder
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

  version :rescaled do
    process :encode
  end
    
  def encode
    movie = ::FFMPEG::Movie.new(current_path)
    tmp_path = File.join( File.dirname(current_path),   "tmpfile.mp4" )
    options = ""
    movie.transcode(tmp_path, options)
    File.rename tmp_path, current_path
  end


  version :thumb do
    process thumbnail: [{format: 'png', quality: 10, size: 400, strip: true, logger: Rails.logger}]
    def full_filename for_file
      png_name for_file, version_name
    end
  end

  def png_name for_file, version_name
    %Q{#{version_name}_#{for_file.chomp(File.extname(for_file))}.png}
  end


  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "system/carrierwave/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

in my article.rb

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  enum category: ["care_article", "share_article", "grow_article"]
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader  
  has_one_attached :video, default: ""
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 25 }
  validates :desc, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 400 }
  validates :category, presence: true, default: 0
  has_one_attached :picture, default: ""
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  is_impressionable
    
  process_in_background :video

  def set_success(format, opts)
    #self.success = true
  end

  def thumbnail_url
    if video_processing
      ""
    else
      video.thumb.url
    end
  end

  # All attachables should have the image_path method, this is sent to API
  def image_path
    thumbnail_url
  end

  def video_path
    # Serve the raw video until the processing is done.
    if video_processing
      video.url
    else
      video.rescaled.url
    end
  end
end
```

in my _article.html.erb

```
    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="box">
            <% if article.video? %>
                <video controls src="<%= article.video %>" width="480" height="auto" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="muted" currentTime poster=".png"></video> 
                <!--    <   %= video_tag(article.video, autoplay: :autoplay, loop: :loop, muted: :muted, class: "article_video") %> -->
                Title) <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %>
            <% else article.picture.present? %>
                <%= link_to image_tag(article.picture, width: 350, class: "shadow rounded"), article_path(article)%>
                Title) <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %>
            <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

what should I do??

Thanks your answer.

Comment: So what does `<%= article.video %>` return exactly, s the URL to the location of the video?  Have you verified the path is correct?  Try hard coding it in  once to see if it works.

Comment: @RockwellRice   below. When i click view-source code, 
<%= article.video %> return src = "#&lt;ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fb671d2eab8&gt;"  ...
how can i fix that??